# sessionStorage.setItem with JSON.stringify causes javascript function to fail

Tags: javascript, json

I am storing two items in sessionStorage, an integer and a string array.  I can see the items in Chrome Dev Console (Application - sessionStorage) and they are correct.

The values as it shows now in the Chrome Dev Console are:

```
HTTP_Index 4
HTTP_History ["Start","text_14","text_7","text_10"]
```

In a javascript function, I retrieve them from sessionStorage:

```
var HTTP_Index = sessionStorage.getItem(HTTP_Index);
var HTTP_History = sessionStorage.getItem(HTTP_History);

p_Index = JSON.parse(HTTP_Index);
p_History = JSON.parse(HTTP_History);
```

I decrement the index:

```
p_Index = p_Index - 1;
console.log("HTTP_Index Now " + p_Index);
```

and the log shows that the value is now 3.

Next I store the value p_Index back to sessionStorage:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("HTTP_Index", JSON.stringify({ "p_Index" });
```

Whether I enclose p_Index in quotes or not, the dev console now shows the function as "undefined."

Next I tried to do it like this:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("HTTP_Index", JSON.stringify({ "p_Index" });
```

but same problem.  So finally I tried this:

```
var obj = { HTTP_Index: p_Index };
var objJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
sessionStorage.setItem(objJSON);
```

But the Chrome dev console shows:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setItem' on 'Storage': 2 arguments required, but only 1 present.
```

What am I doing wrong in using JSON.stringify for sessionStorage.setItem?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `.setItem` you must set a key, and then the value you want to store.

In the case of your first example, you're doing this but have made a simple typo. Also you want to stringify the contents in `p_Index`, not the string `"p_index"`, so, you need to remove your quotes around it when stringifying:

```
sessionStorage.setItem("HTTP_Index", JSON.stringify(p_Index)); // <-- missing this closing bracket
```

And so you'll get a syntax error here.

In the case of your second example (attempt), you're not using valid syntax as you're setting an object with no value.

In your third example, you're trying to set the value to be the stringified object (so your value is just the string, not the object), and so you're not specifying a *key*. To do this you can use:

```
var objJSON = JSON.stringify(p_index);
sessionStorage.setItem("HTTP_Index", objJSON);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  I edited my question re the first example you cite because it did have the closing brace, I just left it out when I posted.  I will try your second one and post back.

Comment: Thanks, Nick.  Your third item did the trick.  var objJSON = JSON.stringify(p_Index);
  sessionStorage.setItem("HTTP_Index", objJSON);

Comment: @RTC222 no worries, glad to help :)

Answer (score 1):

In your latest example:

```
var obj = { HTTP_Index: p_Index };
var objJSON = JSON.stringify(obj);
sessionStorage.setItem(objJSON);
```

sessionStorage.setItem first argument must be the key which you want to set and the 2nd is the data which you are going to store.
So you miss the key/name.